# Text repeats endlessly

Tags: support, comments, editing, answers, specific-answer

In [my answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74990)
while trying to edit, parts of the post kept repeating endlessly so that at some point it reached the limit of 30000 characters!

The repeats are visible in the history

Again this happened in a comment which quickly reached over 2000 characters

I guess there's some infinite loop somewhere...

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Is this not fixed in the latest revision?

Comment: @JJJ Are you asking about the specific question? Then yes. But I am asking about the general arbitrarily repeating behavior

Comment: Okay, so how does it happen? When you start editing the question, it adds in more text than you're trying to put in?

Comment: @JJJ Seems so... I dont see it appearing. But I see odd lengths at times (like suddenly "YOur comment is 2000 characters too long") and the results. Totally garbled

Comment: Of course if it was happening all the time I would not be able to type even this!!!

Comment: @JJJ re the added tag "specific-answer".  Note this happened in an unrelated comment on a different question

Comment: Okay I added some tags, can you try to replicate it in a comment here under this question? Maybe by editing a new comment?

Comment: @JJJ Well I've been doing that as you see and the problem is not repeating (here).  What triggers I dont know

Comment: Okay, can you say which comment it happened on? Did it happen only when you tried to edit the comment or did it happen on the initial version?

Comment: @JJJ I guess it was here https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74908/is-there-a-way-to-exist-notwithstanding-the-current-political-polarization/74919#comment313777_74919

Comment: Okay, I don't t see something weird in the revisions there. Are you sure it's not something on your end that added more text into the box causing the character limit to increase? Maybe some text was pasted more than once?

Comment: @JJJ its unlikely you'll see those posts because I was getting "comment is 2000-something characters too long" already. So its likely it does not go any further than my browser/control.  In the same way you wont see the 30,000+ char version of the answer. Maybe this is better moved to (centralized) meta?

Comment: And when you expand the text box, does it show that more text is added than you intended? Is it just the same text that you were typing or copy pasting or is it sometimes text you don't recognize? It seems kind of weird to me, though if it's only happening in your browser, and seeing that there don't seem to be other user experiencing the same problem, I'm fairly sure it's something going wrong on your end.